# Automatically set current school-year as a batch file setting

Tags: datetime, batch-file

I have a batch file that references the current school-year. At the moment I need to change the line "set SchoolYear=t20172018" manually every year. I've tried to find a more elegant solution, but so far without success. The school-year typically runs from the 1st of august to the 30th of June the following year.

Example:

```
set PSScript="C:\converter\Powershell\somescript.ps1"
set sourcePath="C:\Converter\Output"
set archivePath="C:\Converter\Archive"
set logPath="C:\Converter\Log"
set SchoolYear=t20172018
Rem # Uploading data
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned  -Command "& '%PSScript%' '%sourcePath%' '%archivePath%' '%logPath%' '%SchoolYear%'"
```

Is it possible to have the batch file automatically change the 'set schoolyear=t20XX20XX' on the 1st of august every year?

Comment: just out of curiosity: why not completely in Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you explicitely asked for a batch solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value^|find "="') do set dt=%%a
set y=%dt:~0,4%
set d=%dt:~4,4%
if "%d%" lss "0801" set /a y -= 1
set /a ny=y+1
set schoolyear=t%y%%ny%
echo %schoolyear%
```

using `wmic` might be more complicated than using `%date%`, but it's independent of locale settings.

Note: `if` is comparing strings here, not dates, but as we got the date in `MMDD` format, we can easily compare "dates"

Comment: You miss a `t` in the schoolyear variable. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
SET "check_date=%DATE:~0,2%"
SET "check_date=%DATE:~3,-5%%check_date%"
SET "current_year=%DATE:~6%"
SET /A "next_year=%current_year%+1"
SET /A "last_year=%current_year%-1"

IF "%check_date%" GEQ "0801" (SET "SchoolYear=t%current_year%%next_year%") ELSE (SET "SchoolYear=t%last_year%%current_year%")
```

The date scheme is `DD.MM.YYYY`, if the scheme on your machine is `MM/DD/YYYY` you need to adjust the 2nd line to: `SET "check_date=%check_date%%DATE:~3,-5%"`

Comment: you might want to rethink the `==` ;)

Comment: I tested it and it worked... `==` is used to compare strings, isn't it?

Comment: and what`s the schoolyear at 02Aug or 30Jun?

Comment: ***Mindblown*** ... ehm... yeah... ._.